# change input text value with js or jQuery before submit if value is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I with js or jQuery change input text value with js or jQuery before submit if the input value is null ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

With [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can bind a callback to the submit event with the [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) method.

```
$("form").submit(function(){
   // Let's find the input to check
   var $input = $(this).find("input[name=whatever]");
   if (!$input.val()) {
     // Value is falsey (i.e. null), lets set a new one
     $input.val("whatever you want");
   }
});
```

*Notice: To ensure that all the elements can be found it should be placed in a [domready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.*

Comment: Can you explain the Notice: message more?  Are you saying that you need to wrap the entire thing in: $(document).ready(function() { YOURCODEHERE });

Comment: @tgharold No, because it's not related to the question. The whole thing is thoroughly explaining in the provided link.

Answer (score 3):

With plain DOM (no library), your HTML will look something like:

```
<form name="foo" action="bar" method="post">
    <!-- or method="get" -->
    <input name="somefield">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And your script will look something like this:

```
var form = document.forms.foo;
if (form && form.elements.something)
    // I use onsubmit here for brevity. Really, you want to use a 
    // function that uses form.attachEvent or form.addEventListener
    // based on feature detection.
    form.onsubmit = function() {
        // if (form.elements.foo.value.trim()) is preferable but trim()
        // is not available everywhere. Note that jQuery has $.trim(),
        // and most general purpose libraries include a trim(s)
        // function.
        if (form.elements.something.value.match(/^\s*$/)))
            form.elements.something.value = 'DEFAULT VALUE';
    };
```

Comment: I think you meant `form.elements.somefield` and not `form.elements.something`.